# Will the global catalogs in two forests with transitive trust replicate data?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

Suppose I have two Active Directory forests, each with one global catalog. There is a transitive trust between these forests. Does this imply that data is replicated between the two forests?

Can I perform searches on one global catalog and get results from both catalogs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this imply that data is replicated between the two forests?

Yes, but not to the degree you think of. Naturally certain elements will be replicated - those that are needed to maintain a trust relationship.

But no user level data. Stuff like passwords etc. do NOT leave a forest.

> Can I perform searches on one global catalog and get results from both catalogs?

No. And if you think about it, it makes sense.

For example, the schemata of both forests can be different. If one object has been extended - what would the schema on the other forest do? Trust is not about syncing data, it is about allowing security contexts to pass.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. There is no replication of data between global catalogs in separate forests.